# Corner of table in a certain degree/angle

Tags: html, css, border, angle

i am trying to develop tables where the right border/corner has a certain angle (30°). I have seen some similar solutions, but none of them work with certain degrees. If i want to change from 30° to 20°, i don't wanna put much effort in it.

I hope you can help me further with this, because none of my solutions worked.

It does not matter, if i use it on a table or div's as long as the solution is working.

Thank you very much

Comment: What does the table look like? Dark borders around the table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `border-raduis` property, for your case you can use the `border-top-right-radius` property defines the shape of the border of the **top-right corner**.

```css
td {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
table{

 border:2px solid blue;
 border-top-right-radius : 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius : 10px;

}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how dynamic this is, but I would use an absolute `::after` element, rotate it, and then "push" it into place with `right` and `top`. You would need to change the right and top every time you change the degree.

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -34px;
  right: -16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

td {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr><tr>
</table>
```